# EXO v2 PowerShell: Pass group name into Get-DistributionGroupMember output

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Assuming we have a list of email groups (e.g.): `[array]$Groups=("foo","bar","bing")`

How can we include each group's name with output from: `Get-DistributionGroupMember`

(e.g.): `$Groups | Get-DistributionGroupMember | select alias,[group name that was piped]`

I know the answer is right in front of me, I just can't see it!
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... this works!

```
foreach ($group in $groups) {
Get-DistributionGroupMember $group | select alias, @{N='groupname';E={$group}}
}
```

If there's a better or alternate strategy for similar situations feel free to share!

- updated to remove "-PipelineVariable $group" per AdminOfThings comment

Comment: `-PipelineVariable` is not necessary here since `$group` will already be assigned with the name. This seems like a fine enough solution to me.

Comment: @AdminOfThings Thanks! There's no way around using a custom property to pass it in though, correct?  That was what was throwing me off most.  E.g. `foreach ($group in $groups) { Get-DistributionGroupMember $group -PipelineVariable $group | select alias, $group }` would put the first group as the column header, not populate each row.  I really need to revisit the fundamentals here.

Comment: The particular approach you are using is called a calculated property. If you have an object with a certain set of properties, there are many ways to do what you want. However, essentially one of two things happen: 1) You create a calculated property on output without changing the piped in object. 2) You can add the property to your object through Add-Member or create a custom object with the properties you want. When you pipe to `Select-Object`, a custom object is created. You can pre-create the calculated property as a variable and then use `Select-Object $variable` also.